# Pass value from Child component to Parent component , after child is initialized

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

Now I am passing value from child to parent while click on send button, how to pass the same array child is initialized , I tried with 'ngAfterViewInit' but didn't work, Any recommendation here.

```
      child
    @Component({
        selector: 'app-child',
        templateUrl: './child.component.html'
    })
    export class ChildComponent {

        cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "BMW", 'Saab'];

        @Output() msEvent = new EventEmitter();

        constructor() {}

        send() {

            this.msEvent.emit(this.cars);
        }

        // ngAfterViewInit() {

        //   this.msEvent.emit(this.cars);
        // }
    }

    }
        child.component.html : <button (click) = 'send()' class="button">send</button>
    ----------------------------------------

    parent
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  cars:any[];

  constructor() {

  }
  rece($event) {
    this.cars = $event;
  }
}
    app.component.html : <app-child (msEvent) = 'rece($event)' [employees] = 'employees'></app-child>
```

Comment: It works just fine for me in ngAfterViewInit.  When that code was uncommented you also had "export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngOnInit() is should be enough for your case, because data you pass does not depended on "view".
check here : [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmjvwh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)